# Place to store bags in Seattle for a few hours

Tags: luggage-storage, seattle

Going to be in Seattle for a few hours before making my way to the hotel at Sea-Tac.

Will have a large backpack with me. Would like to dump it somewhere so I can explore the city for the afternoon without lugging it around.

Are there any lockers at the light rail stations or elsewhere I could store the bag for a few hours?

Comment: You have to be taking the train/show them your ticket to store luggage at the Amtrak station.

Comment: You must have an Amtrak ticket to store luggage

Comment: Here is a great new resource I've found seattlehourlystorage.com Super quick and easy

Comment: You bags can be secured @ Northwest Tribal Art located at 1417 1st Ave Seattle, Near Pike Place Fish Market. It is a Bag BNB Angel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Head to the [Amtrak King Street Station](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=am%2Fam2Station%2FStation_Page&code=SEA). They don't have luggage lockers, but they do offer *Baggage Storage* for a small fee (click to the Baggage tab to see that).

[This thread](http://discuss.amtraktrains.com/index.php?/topic/32542-bag-storage-at-seattles-king-street-station/) suggests it was $3 per piece of luggage in 2010, it may well be a little higher now. King Street station is very close to a light rail stop, for when you want to head onwards to the airport.

(There used to be lockers at the bus station, but I don't know if they're still there. The bus station isn't that handy for exploring the city, or getting to the airport, so you'd probably want to head to King Street to store your bags even if you did come in by bus)

Comment: Just called. King Street Station still offers this for $4 per item per day.

Comment: One of the comments above says that you need an Amtrak ticket to store luggage.  Do you know of any other alternatives?

Comment: I have used the check-in luggage service at Amtrak, however, in 2017 I had to provide a copy of my ticket for that day.

Comment: Just checked the website and Amtrack station will store bags for non-ticket holders at $20 per bag per 24 hours.

Comment: For ticket holders is 10 dollars. I just paid.