# How to take care of my bags with a 2:45h break in a train journey in Seattle?

Tags: luggage, sightseeing, seattle, train-stations

I have a ticket booked from Vancouver to Portland in August with a three hour break between 11:15am and 2pm in Seattle. I'd like to try and fit in as much as I can (including some lunch) but I'm not sure whether I will can do with my bags - can I check them straight back in or indeed check them through and not have to do anything with them? How much time out of the station will I realistically have and what essential sights should I think about reaching?

Comment: Sights which you might be considered off-topic on this website, I suggest you remove any opinion-based questions from your question.

Comment: Related: [Place to store bags in Seattle for a few hours](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/place-to-store-bags-in-seattle-for-a-few-hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the day and how busy they are, you might be able to just check them in for your next trip.  I did it quite early for one from Seattle to Portland as well - very similar trip actually.  As you approach the ticket windows, on your left is the baggage check in and the guy will give you a ticket for it.

Alternatively, if they say it's too early, they do offer a [checked baggage storage option](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=am%2Fam2Station%2FStation_Page&code=SEA) (click the 'baggage' tab half way down the page).